# How do I create a new NSDate object that is in the past, e.g. 1 second earlier than another date?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

**So this is how I set a future date:**

```
var comp = NSDateComponents()
comp.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth);
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
var expirationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(comp, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
```

Now what if I have dateA and want to create a new date (dateB) that is 1 second earlier than dateA.

Comment: To subtract one *second*, you can simply do `let dateB = dateA.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-1)`. – For days and larger units, `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can achieve this by changing your second line from `1 to -1` and NSCalendarUnit `Month to Second`

```
var comp = DateComponents()
comp.setValue(-1, for: .second)
let date = Date()
let expirationDate = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: comp, to: date)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Oh, I thought that wouldn't work so didn't try. I will give it a try now.

Comment: 1 second earlier so NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth should be NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond